# Parsing xml file error

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to transform an XML file into a document like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse("C:/xml/41111208890622000144550010000000011000003066-nfe.xml"); 
Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("C:/xml/41111208890622000144550010000000011000003066-nfe.xml")));
```

but it is giving the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1;
```

someone knows what to do?

Comment: What's the content of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently creating a reader containing the *string*

```
"C:/xml/41111208890622000144550010000000011000003066-nfe.xml"
```

and asking the `DocumentBuilder` to parse that as if it were XML, when it's clearly not. (I'm referring to the second `parse` call, which I suspect is the one in your actual code. The code you've provided wouldn't compile as you've declared `document` twice.)

You can create a `FileInputStream` or perhaps an `InputStreamReader` wrapped around it:

```
String filename = "C:/xml/41111208890622000144550010000000011000003066-nfe.xml";
try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename))
{
    Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(input));
}
```

(I prefer to use a stream directly, and let the parser detect the encoding.)

Now this call:

```
Document document = db.parse("C:/xml/...");
```

would *nearly* work and may *actually* work, using [`DocumentBuilder.parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) - it depends on whether `parse` is happy to handle a filename as a URI. (I've seen some XML APIs that are fine with that, and some that aren't.) If it doesn't work, try using the `file://` scheme:

```
Document document = db.parse("file://C:/xml/...");
```

Comment: Not quite. The `DocumentBuilder#parse(String)` method takes a URL (in string form) and parses the content of that location. This is in fact a safer method than the `InputStream` version, since the parser is given the base URI (system ID) and can use it for resolving other resources, if needed.

Comment: @forty-two: When you say "not quite" - unless there *are* other (relative) resources in the XML, this works fine, right? (My claim of "needing" to do this is wrong, admittedly - will edit that.)

Comment: "Not quite" referred to the implication that `#parse(String)` takes an XML string, which it doesn't.

Comment: @forty-two: I was referring to the second call to `parse`, which takes an `InputSource` built with a `StringReader`. That *is* trying to parse the filename as if it's XML, which explains the exception. I've clarified slightly - it really doesn't help that the code wouldn't even have compiled.

Comment: @forty-two: Does my answer make more sense now? I've added a bit about the `parse(String)` method as well though.

Comment: Yes, sure, sorry for the confusion :-)